# Math Test review on probability and statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

A committee of 11 members is voting on a proposal. Each member casts a YES or NO vote. On a random voting basis, what is the probability that the proposal wins by a vote of 8 to 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Binomial Distribution (probability of x successes in n trials), where success denotes a YES vote.

Let the number of YES votes be represented by random variable X.

$n=11$, $x=8$, $p=1/2$

$X \sim \text{Binomial}(11, 1/2)$.

$$ P(X = 8) = {11 \choose 8}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{8}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

My probability is rusty... but maybe this helps.

Let $X$ be the number of "no" votes. Suppose that a "yes" or "no" is equally likely. Then, $X$ is a binomial random variable with probability $p = 1/2$ and $n = 11$ trials.

i.e. $X \sim \text{Binomial}(1/2,11)$.

Then,

$$ P(X = 3) = {11 \choose 3}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{3}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{8} \approx 8.05\%$$

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks for the help.